# How to make Excel 2013 and 2016 PivotTables' line color black?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

Excel changed the default line colors of its PivotTables (PivotTable Tools > Design > PivotTable Style > None) from black (2010 and before) to a very light grey (2013 and 2016). This makes the tables very hard to read on screen and in print. Is there anyway to change the line colors back to black without affecting the format of the PivotTable itself or resorting to VBA?